# how to send data to html in Angular using d3.js after on click piechart slice

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, angular6

I am having a pie chart with slices on it. when you clicked on a slice related content to it should display to other component's html on same page.but for d3.js onclick, I am not able to display the data on html.

```
 draw(){  
    console.log(TempData);
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var previous;
    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#ddd", "#ddd", "#ddd", "#ddd", "#ddd", "#ddd", "#ddd"]);

    var arcOver = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(60)
      .outerRadius(radius+20);

    var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

    var path = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(60);

    var label = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 60)
    .innerRadius(radius - 60);

    var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(this.data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    arc.append("path")
    .attr("d", path).style("stroke","black").style('stroke-width', 0.35)
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); })
    .on("click",function(d) {  
      d3.select(previous).transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .attr("d", path);
        d3.select(this).transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .attr("d", arcOver);

        var rotate = 180-(d.startAngle + d.endAngle)/2 / Math.PI * 180;

       g.transition()
        .attr("transform",  "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ") rotate(" + (rotate-90) + ")")
        .duration(1000);

      text.transition()
       .attr("transform", function(dd) {
         return "translate(" + label.centroid(dd) + ") rotate(" + (-rotate+90) + ")"; })
       .duration(1000);

      previous=this;

      this.parentMessage = d.data.age;
      console.log(this.parentMessage);
     });
```

When I did console.log(this.parentMessage); It is showing on console but getting display the same on html.
here is my HTML code,

```
<div style="text-align:center;background-color:lightblue" >
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!

  </h1>
</div>

<div>
<div style="float:left; background-color:seagreen">
  <svg width="600" height="350" style="position:absolute;left:-300;margin-top: 100px;"></svg>
</div>
<div style="float:right;background-color:seagreen;margin-top: 100px;">
  <app-pie-details [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-pie-details>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the draw function you've added inside of the component which is containing your d3 graphic?